# Why would upgrading a service plan from Basic to Standard tier in Azure App Services fail?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a basic level service plan in the new Azure portal, but discover I need a higher level to poll Service Bus topics more often than once an hour.

Trying to upgrade through the portal I receive the message:

> **Failed to update App Service plan** 
>   Failed to update App Service plan {PlanName}: There was an error processing your request.
>   Please try again in a few moments.

I have retried several times and receive the same error with each attempt.

What might cause this (rather uninformative) error, and how can I correct it?

Comment: No solution, but I have the exact same problem. Stumbled upon this b/c i needed to upload my SSL and that is not supported by the Basic plan.

Comment: My only solution was to delete and create a new plan.

Comment: Well, it is *not* user friendly, but inline with how MS implemented resource group support in the 'new' portal. I love Azure, but I am really disapointed in the UI of the new portal.

Comment: Using Azure for a few years now and I no longer even bother looking for rename/update/modify buttons. It's always delete and recreate the entire thing from scratch...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just occurred to me, that you can still do this in the 'old' portal. Just verified the work-around and it works!

Comment: Sure, go to the particular website in the old portal; Choose configure; Change the tier; Click save.

As far as i could verify, this modified the plan linked to the website. At least the site is now in the right tier.